# javascript select spesified element on click event

Tags: javascript

i have a problem about getting **spesified** element that i need to.

so, this is my code :

```
<p class="prev">prev</p>
<p class="next">next</p>

<ul class="parent">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>

document.querySelectorAll(".next")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var x = querySelectorAll(".parent li")[2].innerHTML;
    alert(x);  // output 2

});

document.querySelectorAll(".prev")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var x = querySelectorAll(".parent li")[2].innerHTML;
    alert(x);  // output -2

});
```

so, if i click **.next** the output will ---> 2 ----> again ----> 6 ----> again ----> 8 ----> and again ----> 10

**.prev** also ---> from 10 to 8 from 8 to 6 from 6 to 4 from 4 to 2 from 2 to 0

so, how exactly to solve this problem?

Comment: It's `document.querySelectorAll` for a start.

Comment: tjhanks andy for the correction, i just want to make my questions become simple and readable.

Comment: It would be nice if you up all helpfull answers 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you want the end output to go to zero, but you have no element with that content so you need to add it in. Regardless here's some working code.

I've used ids for the `next` and `prev` buttons because that makes more sense, and I've separated out the code so it's a little easier to read. I also moved the `li` selection outside of the function because you only need to pick them up once, not every time you call one of the functions. Note, this logs to the console rather than an alert because it made it easier to test the code.

```
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var lis = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li");

next.addEventListener('click', advance, false);
prev.addEventListener('click', retreat, false);

var index = 0;

function advance() {
    if (index + 2 < lis.length - 1) {
        index += 2;
        console.log(lis[index].innerHTML);
    }
}

function retreat() {
    if (index > 0) {
        index -= 2;
        console.log(lis[index].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bg3k5soa/8/)

Comment: thank you so much Andy , i think this is more simple, i like that. because i'm beginner at javascript. anyway, CodeiSir's method also working.  thanks guys!

Comment: This has possible erorrs as well.

Comment: @CodeiSir, no it doesn't. Perhaps you can say what errors you're getting. And what is a "possible error"?

Comment: It does. Im just unhappy i got no points for my solution, and set yours has possible errors. But I like your solution otherwise

Comment: You might have an index bigger then elements, if the amount of elements is odd, and also the index might go under 0 from a odd index

Comment: Fair point. Thanks. FYI @ChingChing, made a small change to the code/demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```js
var index = 0;

document.querySelectorAll(".prev")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  index = index - 2;
  if (index < 0) { // don't go below 0
    index = 0; // correct it
  } else {
    // Goto Previous Element
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li")[index].innerHTML;
    alert(x);
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll(".next")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var index_max = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li").length - 1;
  index = index + 2;
  if (index > index_max) { // don't go futher than elements exist
    index = index_max; // correct it
  } else {
    // Goto Next Element
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".parent li")[index].innerHTML;
    alert(x);
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="prev">prev</p>
<p class="next">next</p>
<ul class="parent">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You rock CodeiSir! thank you so much for your method... yeahhh